# Silent Exception On Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exception

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ///IDE will notify me of this exception  
    throw new Exception();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //IDE will not notify me of this exception  
    throw new Exception();


    //code will not execute  
    MessageBox.Show("test");
}
```

why?

----------------------EDITED----------------------
the correct answer is what [ChrisA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24867/chrisa) mentioned.
some quotes from microsoft :

> This is a known bug with x64 versions
>   of Windows and the way exceptions are
>   handled. One way to work around this
>   issue while debugging is to go to the
>   Debug -> Exceptions and select
>   'Thrown' for for the exception types
>   you are interested in. This will stop
>   the debugger when the exception is
>   first hit (and before Windows eats it
>   up).

---

> This bug was closed as "External"
>   because this behavior results from how
>   x64 version of Windows handle
>   exceptions. When a user mode exception
>   crosses a kernel transition, x64
>   versions of Windows do not allow the
>   exception to propagate. Therefore
>   attached debuggers are unaware of the
>   fact that an exception occured
>   resulting in the debugger failing to
>   break on the unhandled exception.
>
> Unfortunately where is nothing that
>   the Visual Studo team can do to
>   address this, it is the result of
>   operating system design. All feedback
>   regarding this issue should be
>   addressed to the Windows team; however
>   the Windows team considers this to be
>   the "correct" operating system design,
>   and considers the x86 behavior to be
>   "incorrect".

---

> This hotfix has not undergone full
>   testing. Therefore, it is intended
>   only for systems or computers that are
>   experiencing the exact problem that is
>   described in the one or more Microsoft
>   Knowledge Base articles that are
>   listed in "KB Article Numbers" field
>   in the table at the end of this e-mail
>   message. If you are not sure whether
>   any special compatibility or
>   installation issues are associated
>   with this hotfix, we encourage you to
>   wait for the next service pack
>   release. The service pack will include
>   a fully tested version of this fix. We
>   understand that it can be difficult to
>   determine whether any compatibility or
>   installation issues are associated
>   with a hotfix. If you want
>   confirmation that this hotfix
>   addresses your specific problem, or if
>   you want to confirm whether any
>   special compatibility or installation
>   issues are associated with this
>   hotfix, support professionals in
>   Customer Support Services can help you
>   with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you developing on an x64 machine?

If so, you might like to have a look at [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/357311/silent-exceptions-on-x64-development-machines?wa=wsignin1.0).

That thread also refers to [a very detailed explanation](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/) of the whole issue.

This, and [another show stopper](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/msbuild/thread/e5900710-9849-4d10-aa28-48b734d06bf2) (for me anyway, the workarounds didn't work for me, or my colleague) on x64, resulted in a rebuild of my dev box with win7 x86.

The problems have all gone away now.  But it's very disappointing.

Comment: yes! that was awesome! I edit the question so it would be a reference here.